# How to hide content when a radio button is not checked and enable other content to be viewed

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog

Basically i want to set up two radio buttons, one called 'Login' and the other called 'Register'

When the 'Login' radio button is checked i want the login section to be shown only and vise versa for the 'Register' button.

Any help is greatly appreciated

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h2 class="text-center"><img src="//placehold.it/110" class="img-circle"><br>Login</h2>
                <div class="container">
  <form role="form">
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="optradio">Login
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="optradio">Register
    </label>
  </form>
</div>
            </div>
            <div style="width:602px"class="modal-body row">
                                    <form action="" method="post">
                                            <div class="row">
                                            <div style="padding-left:20px; padding-right:-20px class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="username">Username</label>
                                            <input id="name" name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text" tabindex="1" class="form-control">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="password">Password</label>
                                            <input id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password"   tabindex="2" class="form-control">
                                            <br>
                                            <input class="form-control btn btn-success" name="submit" type="submit" value="Log In" id="submit" tabindex="4" >
                                            <h4>Not a member? <label class="checkbox-Warning"><input type="checkbox" value=""></label></h4>
                                            <!-- come back here and finished login and registration -->



                                    <div class="text-center"><h3 style="text-align:center"><b>Register</b></h3></div>
                                    <form id="register-form" action="index.php" method="post" role="form">
                                        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                                            <label for="username">Username</label>
                                            <span class="form-control-feedback input-validator-feedback" data-fieldname="username"></span>
                                            <input type="text" name="newusername" id="newusername" tabindex="1" class="form-control validate-input" placeholder="Username" value="" autocomplete="off">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                                            <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                                            <span class="form-control-feedback input-validator-feedback" data-fieldname="email"></span>
                                            <input type="text" name="newemail" id="email" tabindex="2" class="form-control validate-input" placeholder="Email Address" value="" autocomplete="off">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="password">Password</label>
                                            <input type="password" name="newpassword1" id="password" tabindex="3" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="confirm-password">Confirm Password</label>
                                            <input type="password" name="confirm-password1" tabindex="4" id="confirm-password1" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password" autocomplete="off">
                                            <br>
                                                <input type="submit" name="register-submit" id="register-submit" tabindex="5" class="form-control btn btn-success" value="Register">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>  
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

so all of the login should be visible when the login radio button is checked and all the register components should be hidden

Comment: Welcome to the stack and sorry to say that it is difficult to find any help if you do not provide any code and just paste a pic.

Comment: I carnt add a pic :/ should i add an external link to one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added an id to both of the buttons for document.getElementById.

```
<input type="radio" name="optradio" value="login" id="login-button" >
<input type="radio" name="optradio" value="register" id="register-button">
<script>
document.getElementById("login-button").addEventListener("click", function(){
     document.querySelector('#login-div').style.display = 'initial';
     document.querySelector('#register-div').style.display = 'none';
}, false);
document.getElementById("register-button").addEventListener("click", function(){
     document.querySelector('#register-div').style.display = 'initial';
     document.querySelector('#login-div').style.display = 'none';
}, false);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could give the radio buttons different classes/id's, for example "registerbutton" and "loginbutton".

If you give the register part the class/id "register" and the login part the class/id "login", you can target them with jQuery.

You can put the following code between `<script>` tags.

```
$('.registerbutton').click( function() {
   $('.login').css('display', 'none')
   $('.register').css('display', 'inline-block')
});

$('.loginbutton').click( function() {
   $('.login').css('display', 'inline-block')
   $('.register').css('display', 'none')
});
```

jQuery works with css selectors, so '.loginbutton' is something with the class loginbutton. If you give the elements id's you should replace '.loginbutton' with '#loginbutton'.

I don't know if you've worked with jQuery yet, but if you haven't: don't forget to link a jQuery library. Don't forget it either when you have worked with it.

If you put this at the right before the closing `</body>` tag it should work.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $('.registerbutton').click( function() {
      $('.login').css('display', 'none')
      $('.register').css('display', 'inline-block')
   });

   $('.loginbutton').click( function() {
      $('.login').css('display', 'inline-block')
      $('.register').css('display', 'none')
   });
</script>
```

The first `<script>` tag links the library with functions and the second tag calls the functions to make the thing work. If you give de html elements the right classes/id's.

Comment: No idea what jQuery is, and even less idea how to set this up

Comment: @OliverKetley I don't know if you get notified when I update answers, but I did. I hope it works now.

Comment: I dont see and update nor did i get a notification, what was it that you updated, thanks

Comment: The second code block is new. It's how you can put jQuery in html.

Answer (score 0):

Setup an event handler to notice if a radio button is ticked, and that responds to click events on the radio buttons.

With jQuery:

```
$("input[type=radio]").on('click', function () {
   $(container).empty();
   var newSection = $('input[type=radio]:checked').value; //Get name of the new section
   $(container).append($('div.' + newSection));
});
```

On this click event, remove the html in the section and append the new section you'd like.

This answer doesn't necessarily tailor to your current code but is a concept for how you could approach it

Comment: But how would i get it to hide the other unneeded contents and i would prefer to use javascript Thanks for the guidance